# Correct code for imputation with fancyimpute

Tags: python, imputation, fancyimpute

I was performing an imputation of missing values by `KNN` with this code:

1) `data[missing] = KNN(k = 3, verbose = False).fit_transform(data[missing])`

However, I saw some tutorials (e.g. [Chris Albon - Machine Learning With Python Cookbook p. 78](https://books.google.de/books?id=kIhQDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT76&dq=features_knn_imputed%20%3D%20KNN(k%3D5,%20verbose%3D0).complete(standardized_features)&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPhpaVyf_kAhUk_CoKHdUqCK4Q6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=features_knn_imputed%20%3D%20KNN(k%3D5%2C%20verbose%3D0).complete(standardized_features)&f=false)) that used the method `.complete()`;

2) `features_knn_imputed = KNN(k=5, verbose=0).complete(X_train[true_nums])`

I was wondering if 2) is deprecated code or if my implementation of `KNN` for imputing in 1) is incorrect?

Comment: could you share the tutorial you were following so we can check it? a quick look at the fancyimpute repo indicates that KNN does not have a method called `complete()`

Comment: Sure, I added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `.complete` is deprecated.
Use `.fit_transform` just like sklearn.

Check the usage here:
https://pypi.org/project/fancyimpute/0.5.5/